# ajax request Mootools to asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, mootools

I am trying to post a request to the server but it wont hit when I use the debugger?

server:

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        public string HitThis()
        {
            return "braza";

        }
    }


 <script type="text/javascript">

        var myRequest = new Request({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/Default.aspx/HitThis',
            onSuccess: function () {
                alert('good');
            },
            onFailure: function () {
                alert('nope');
            }


        });

        myRequest.send();


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to call your `HitThis` method, you need to make that method, static, decorate it with the `Web Method` attribute and enable Page Methods on your `ScriptManager`

Example:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"
       EnablePageMethods="true" />


   [WebMethod]
   public static string HitThis()
   {
       return "Hello World";
   }
```

Comment: Yes, but you are using asp.net, aren't you? Add the markup I posted to your page. It won't hurt you and it will allow you to call your `HitThis` method on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first understand how ASP.NET AJAX Script Services or PageMethod works! Page Methods has to be decorated with the `WebMethod` attribute and needs to be static.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string HitThis()
{
}
```

See [this article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) that illustrates calling page method using jquery. You can adopt it with mootools. However, note that page methods needs content type to be JSON data and response will also be in JSON.

Perhaps you can write your own wiring logic in the ASP.NET page using [Request.PathInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo.aspx) if you want to use normal form posting. For example,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (this.Request.PathInfo == "HitThis")
    {
       HitThis();
    }
}
```

In your method, you need to work with `Response` (HttpResponse) and after modifying the response, you need to end it (HttpResponse.End) so that normal page processing would not happen. If your method needs parameters then you have to pass them via form data and/or query string.

Comment: I am trying :   var jSonRequest = new Request.JSON({ url: 'default.aspx/HelloWorld'}).send(); however this does not work:(